Search Icon Button is not appearing
I'm developing a website. In total there are 4 pages. And only one page show search button icon, others doesn't show.
I'm beginner in coding and cannot find out what is the problem.


.search-container button{
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="mobileMenuContainer">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
                <div class="mobileButtonStyle hamburger perfectCenter"><div></div></div>
                <div class="modal mobileMenu">
                
                <div class="search-container">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
</div>



search button is not appear
this is the only 1 page that could show search button icon
I thought it's html coding problem since one of them could show the icon correctly.
But I couldn't find out where is the problems.

Reworked your question using the css/html feature of so and it seems to show the search button (gray thing on the right).  We generally don't follow external links.

Your button has no value, so it lead to a 0 width of your button. Just add some value to your button. For example <button type="submit">click me<i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>



.search-container button{
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="mobileMenuContainer">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
                <div class="mobileButtonStyle hamburger perfectCenter"><div></div></div>
                <div class="modal mobileMenu">
                
                <div class="search-container">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                        <button type="submit">click me<i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
</div>




Agreed. As long as each page has the div/button set up the same way with classes, etc, once you add some text between the button tags, they should be visible on each page.
